# Solr: Search the list of facets/fields

Tags: solr, lucene, field, facet

My site has a fairly robust set of facets for our SOLR search. We use heirarchical categories, series, locations, authors, etc....

We wanted to add, to our top level search, the ability to not just search within the content of our site, but to search within the facets themselves. Meaning, if the user types in "Mich" they might find results on Michael Jordan or Michael Jackson, but they would also see (probably divided into a different section) that amongst our contributors are authors: "**Mich**ael Thompson" and "Xavier **Mich**aelson" and amongst our venues is: "Battle Creek, **Mich**igan".

Now, I could certainly just search against all of our database tables to find matches, but I was hoping that SOLR has a way of producing search results where facets/fields are the results. Does such a thing exist? Is it easy to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on debug for queries. It would take a bit of parsing to extract, but the debug info contains the fields where the query matched: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debug